# R statistics: problem with simple column vector

Tags: r, statistics

I have a problem using data from a tab delimited data file imported with `read.delim`.

Most of the columns contain numerical data which I need to do a `t.test` for. Unfortunately I always get this error:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) 
            stop("data are essentiallyconstant") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I noticed that this only happens with vectors that consist of different levels.
It won't even perform simple numerical operations like vector[1] + vector[2] for leveled vectors.
Vectors without levels work fine, though.

How can I use the data in the leveled vectors for calculation?

Thank you

Comment: Reproducible example on toy data, please. Also, if you could, try formatting your code using the '1010101' button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce your error message with the following small example:

```
x = as.factor(1:5)
y = as.factor(1:5)

t.test(x, y)
```

yields

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The problem is you are trying to perform a t-test on non-numeric vectors. Addition likewise is not defined for factors:

```
x + y
```

yields

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x, y) : + not meaningful for factors
```

The warning gives keen insight as to what is amiss and also explains why your t-test is not working.

To fix the problem, you need to do as ilya suggests: convert your vectors to numeric with `as.numeric(as.character())`

Comment: The real solution is to find out why your numeric vectors are being converted to factors in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Converting the leveled vectors to numeric with as.numeric(as.character(vector)) solved the problem.
Indeed the entries in the leveled vector were factoral.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that some of your data  may not be in numeric format after loading it. Check the structure of the data with `str(your.data)`. If your your desired variables are not numeric you can convert them with `data$var1 <- as.numeric(data$var1)`.

Comment: Yeah - "leveled vectors" sounds a lot like a factor to me.  On read.delim, you can set the stringsAsFactors argument to FALSE, which will prevent this from happening.  There's also a global stringsAsFactors option (if you look at `?read.delim`, you can see the defaults check this option).  I highly recommend it.

Comment: See also the R FAQ on turning factors to numeric (naked `as.numeric` doesn't work). http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Answer (score 0):

You say "Most of the columns contain numerical data". That's the problem. Only when all columns contain numerical data, can the function apply used without changing the data type. If there is any non-numerical data in other columns, you should change the data type in the function apply:

```
        pvalue<-apply(x,1,ttest<-function(tmp { 
                              if(length(unique(c(tmp[5],tmp[7],tmp[9])))!=1 && 
                              length(unique(c(tmp[11],tmp[13],tmp[15])))!=1) 
                              t.test(c(as.numeric(tmp[5]),as.numeric(tmp[7]),
                              as.numeric(tmp[9])), c(as.numeric(tmp[11]), 
                              as.numeric(tmp[13]),as.numeric(tmp[15])))$p.value 
                              else NA})
```