# "data are essentially constant" error with t test

Tags: r

```
t.test(antibioticdata$Bacteria,
       antibioticdata$Inhibition, 
       alternative = c("two.sided"),
       paired = FALSE, 
       var.equal = FALSE)
```

Here is my R code to make a t-test for a set of data on antibiotic resistance of bacteria. This gives me the error code:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal input data set (the smallest to reproduce) that reproduces this issue ? That may be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: I believe that this gives a clue to what is happening: `Calling var(x) on a factor x`. If one of `Bacteria` or `Inhibition` is a factor then the error and that warning will occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R statistics: problem with simple column vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247178/r-statistics-problem-with-simple-column-vector)

Comment: Please check out the link that is the possible duplicate, this may answer your question.

Comment: FYI, I can reproduce the error message with the following code `t.test(factor(1:10), 1:10)` so it is likely your `Bacteria` is a factor.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], though the error message is clear enough. Are you intentionally using the t-test on categorical data? Since categorical values are not normally distributed and don't even have meaningful means or variances, it isn't clear what you hope to discover by running the test. Maybe R is simply protecting you from statistical nonsense. The answer to "not sure what I am doing wrong" might be "trying to run a t-test on categorical data".

Comment: Please show `class(antibioticdata$Bacteria) ;class(antibioticdata$Inhibition)`

Answer (score 3):

I just met the same error. It's probably due to all the values in each group are the same.

So just write two more "if else". For me, I did

```
library("greenbrown") 

apply(data.table, 1, function(x){

  if(AllEqual(x[1:9])){return(1)}

  else if(AllEqual(x[1:4]) & AllEqual(x[5:9])){return(0)} else {

  t.test(as.numeric(x[1:4]), as.numeric(x[5:9]))->t.results

  return(t.results$p.value)
  }
})->P.for.data.table
```